# TableViewのセルをセクション毎に角丸にしたい

Tags: ios, uitableview

iOS8ではUITableViewのスタイルをグループにしても、セクション毎にグループになっているセルが角丸になりません。
どうすれば、セクション毎に角丸になりますか？

Comment: 本家の方にそれっぽいコードがありました。iOS7ですが...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822619/ios-7-tableview-like-in-settings-app-on-ipad

Comment: まさにこの記事で解決しました。

Comment: @skd 解決できた場合には解決策をご自身で回答として書き込み、それを承認していただけると、他の回答者の方が本質問がクローズしていることがよくわかります。よろしくお願いします。